# Unique Key Error in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework

> ```
> My Class
> ```

```
public  class Dept_Master
 {
   [Key]
   public int Dept_Id { get; set; }
   [Index(IsUnique =true)]
   public string Dept_Name { get; set; }
   public bool status { get; set; }           
}
```

Error on Following

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Column 'Dept_Name' in table 'dbo.Dept_Master' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key columnin an index.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the

> execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column
>   'Dept_Name' in table 'dbo.Dept_Master' is of a type that is invalid
>   for use as a key column in an index.

[image]

Comment: I guess `Dept_Name` is `(n)varchar(max)` which makes it non eligible for unique constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a VARCHAR(Max), we will get this error. Please try using:

```
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[StringLength(n)]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string Dept_Name { get; set; }
```

where n is between 1 and 450.

Answer (score 1):

> Two Way You can assign unique key

```
1)
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(2000)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Dept_Name { get; set; }

2)
   [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]     
   [Index(IsUnique = true)]
   public string Dept_Name { get; set; }
```

> @do not required for String length  varchar datatype